# FindNext issues

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and am looking for some assistance if possible... I am attempting to search a set of data through the use of a user form. Currently I am having an issue with the FindNext... I want the form to cycle trough the data everytime the CommandButton is clicked until it reaches the first found value. Currently my code will find the next itteration and return the value, but will not find the next set of values when you click the CommandButton again. Please help.

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()

    Dim part As String
    Dim rnum As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim firstaddress As String
        
    part = TextBox7.Text
    With Sheets("Raw Survey Data").Columns("E:E")
    Set rng = .Find(part)
        If rng Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "No Shots Found"
            GoTo Ende
        Else
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        Set rng = .FindNext(rng)
        firstaddress = rng.Address
        rnum = rng.Row
    Do
        TextBox7.Text = Sheets("Raw Survey Data").Cells(rnum, 5).Value
        TextBox1.Text = Sheets("Raw Survey Data").Cells(rnum, 1).Value
        TextBox2.Text = Sheets("Raw Survey Data").Cells(rnum, 2).Value
        TextBox3.Text = Sheets("Raw Survey Data").Cells(rnum, 3).Value
        TextBox4.Text = Sheets("Raw Survey Data").Cells(rnum, 4).Value
        TextBox5.Text = Sheets("Raw Survey Data").Cells(rnum, 5).Value
        TextBox6.Text = Sheets("Raw Survey Data").Cells(rnum, 11).Value
        Loop Until rng.Address = firstaddress
    Else
        MsgBox "No more" + part + "shots were found"
    End If
    End If
    End With
Ende:
    
End Sub
```

I have tried a few different ideas from the FindNext function info and am not getting anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

### Find Next String on Next Run

- `FindNext` is used to find multiple occurrences when running a procedure once.
- You could use a module-scoped variable to keep track of each 'matching' row number.
- Not tested!

```vb
Option Explicit

Private CURRENT_ROW As Long ' a module-scoped variable

Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Raw Survey Data")
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Columns("E")
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = ws.Rows.Count
    
    Dim Part As String: Part = TextBox7.Text

    If CURRENT_ROW = 0 Then CURRENT_ROW = rCount
    
    Dim cell As Range:
    Set cell = rg.Find(Part, rg.Cells(CURRENT_ROW), xlFormulas, xlWhole)
    
    If cell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No shots found!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If CURRENT_ROW <> rCount And cell.Row < CURRENT_ROW Then
        CURRENT_ROW = rCount
        MsgBox "No more " + Part + " shots were found!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    Else
        CURRENT_ROW = cell.Row
    End If
    
    With ws.Rows(CURRENT_ROW)
        TextBox7.Text = .Columns("E").Value ' ???
        TextBox1.Text = .Columns("A").Value
        TextBox2.Text = .Columns("B").Value
        TextBox3.Text = .Columns("C").Value
        TextBox4.Text = .Columns("D").Value
        TextBox5.Text = .Columns("E").Value ' ???
        TextBox6.Text = .Columns("K").Value
    End With
    
End Sub
```